# How to check if Interstitial ad is loading with Google Mobile Ads SDK version 20.0.0

Tags: android, interstitial

- For SDK versions earlier than 20.0.0 We can check if Interstitial is loading with this code:

  ```
  private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
  mInterstitialAd.isLoading();
  ```
- For SDK version 20.0.0 We can only check if Interstitial is loaded with this code:

  ```
  InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest,
        new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
        Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
      }
    });
  ```

Is there a method to check if Interstitial ad is loading in SDK version 20.0.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no built-in method to do that, but you can easily do:

```
private boolean isLoaded = false;
private void loadAd(){
   InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest,
       new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
             mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
             isLoaded = true;
             Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
          }
       });
}
```

And then simply get the value of `isLoaded`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isLoaded = false;
private void loadAd(){
isLoaded = false;
InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest,
   new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
         mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
         isLoaded = true;
         Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
      }
      @Override
      public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
      isLoaded = false;
      Log.i(TAG, "Loading ad failed");
      }
   });
```

}